# android app activity lagging behind

Tags: android, xml

i am building an app in android studio,in it i made an activity which has 5 images in it. Due to the images I think that activity is opening and responding very slow. Please help me out on how I can make it fast without removing those images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the images with a new thread to show the UI thread to continue normally. You should use an image loading library such as Picasso instead of doing thrifts from scratch. While this does not technically cause the activity to load faster, it will make your app more responsive.

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: @NamitThakral Do what?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with something like this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

- make sure that ur images arent too high resolution